# Cyclic extension and primes that totally, tamely ramify

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

I am studying algebraic number theory/class field theory. There I need the following result

Let $q$ be a prime in $K$, a number field, and $F$ a finite abelian extension of $K$ such that $F$ contains the Hilbert Class of $K$ and $q$ splits completely in $F$. Let $M$ be a finite extension of $F$, abelian over $K$, such that in $M/F$ all primes above $q$ are totally, tamely ramified and no other primes ramify. Then, $Gal(M/F)$ is cyclic.

I have no idea how to prove it. I tried to use information from cyclotomic fields, because $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p^{n}})/\mathbb{Q}$ is cyclic and ramifies only in $p$. However, I am not sure how to use it and I don't if $p$ totally ramifies.

Comment: If any prime $v$ is totally tamely ramified in $M/F$ then $\mathrm{Gal}(M/F)$ is cyclic. "totally" ramified implies that $\mathrm{Gal}(M/F) = D_v = I_v$, where $D_v$ and $I_v$ are the decomposition and inertia subgroups. "tamely" implies that $I_0 = I_v$ is prime to $p$, or equivalently that the wild inertia subgroup $I_1$ is trivial. But the tame part of inertia $I_0/I_1$ is always cyclic by a standard fact about local fields.

Comment: @user670344 Where can I learn this theory? I agree that totally ramified implies $D_{v}=I_{v}$. But I would like to learn about these other inertia subgroups.

Comment: In any algebraic number theory book? I would be surprised to find one that talks about tame ramification but doesn't talk about the natural filtration(s).

Comment: @mat6676 Serre Local Fields p.67 Cor 1 (chapter 4) says $I_0/I_1$ is cyclic - because it injects into the group of units of the residue field, and a finite subgroup of the units of a field is a cyclic group